# what does memtest86+ serial console mean

Tags: grub2, memtest

In the GRUB, there are 2 options for memory test, memtest86+ and memtest86+ serial console 115200. What the first one means is obvious, it just runs memtest86+, but what does that serial console mean in the second option?

Comment: if running memtest86 on a *headless* device, you're able to access the memtest from a remote screen connected to serial port using speed 115,200bps.

Comment: Thanks guiverc, can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

- **memtest86+**; used for boxes that have a screen attached
- **memtest86+ serial console 115200**; used for *headless* boxes that have a serial terminal/console attached; the 115,200 is the speed (115,200 bps) or the fastest old serial connections (*think RS232; well before USB*) could reliably achieve before needing to *modulate-demodulate* signal etc